# Is the not equals cloud firestore query functionality available for flutter plugin?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So at the start of this month, the firebase team announced [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/09/cloud-firestore-not-equal-queries.html) that the not
equals queries are now available but I am not able to find if this is something I can use in flutter as well. If yes, could you please provide the syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**Update Nov 6, 2020:**

cloud_firestore 0.14.3 now supports != queries using `isNotEqualTo` as seen in the API documentation for [where()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html). If you are using an old version, you will have to upgrade.

**Original answer:**

Firestore's inequality queries are currently not supported in Flutter.  If they were, you would see it in the [API documentation for the `where` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html).  It would also necessitate an update of the written documentation on [query limitations](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#query-limitations), where it currently says:

> Cloud Firestore does not support the following types of queries:
>
> Queries with a != clause. In this cause, you should split the query into a greater-than query and a less-than query. For example, the query clause where("age", isNotEqualTo: 30) is not supported, however you can get the same result set by combining two queries, one with the clause where("age", isLessThan: 30) and one with the clause where("age", isGreaterThan: 30)

The GitHub issue tracking this update is here: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/3748

As of Nov 4, the update is merged and should appear in a future release described in the [release notes](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog).

Comment: The PR to add support for the `!=` and `not in` operations is in https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/pull/3748