# how can i call query with a notEqual (!=) where-clause using **Flutter** cloud_firestore plugin?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

firebase team announced [in this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2020/09/cloud-firestore-not-equal-queries.html) that they now support **notEquals** in where-clause queries,

how can we call such a query in flutter?
i use the [latest version](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) in pubspec.yaml:

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.14.2
```

for instance in firebase this is now (October 1, 2020) possible:

```
collection("projects").where("status", "!=", "completed")
```

and in flutter it's not working (too many positional arguments):

```dart
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("projects").where("status", "!=", "completed");
```

and there is no named arguments for it, the only arguments i can find:

```dart
      Query where(
        dynamic field, {
        dynamic isEqualTo,
        dynamic isLessThan,
        dynamic isLessThanOrEqualTo,
        dynamic isGreaterThan,
        dynamic isGreaterThanOrEqualTo,
        dynamic arrayContains,
        List<dynamic> arrayContainsAny,
        List<dynamic> whereIn,
        bool isNull,
      })
```

does any one have a workaround / idea / solution ?

Comment: If you were the downvoter of this answer, you should know that this is in progress according to the linked information.  Asking the question again doesn't change the facts you see.  It's still in progress.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64406005/is-the-not-equals-cloud-firestore-query-functionality-available-for-flutter-plug/64406282#64406282

Comment: Tried to improve the question with this exact post, it did not allow, figured because it was closed, so i opened this new one, your answer of not supported yet is not a solution, idea or a workaround, i removed my downvote though i think it is not the answer i asked for, that part is a given

Answer (score 1):

Post this answer as a Community Wiki as this was already commented by @DougSteveson and at the related question shared by him.

Firebase does support the `!=` and `not-in` query clauses in it's latest release, you can check it's usage with the official SDK in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators).

However, the **Flutter Firestore libraries were not yet updated**, as this is still a very new feature. Currently the update for this feature is merged and should appear in a future release, as described in the [release notes](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog).